# Geometry Nodes: How to distribute points with a consistent distance to each other but for only one direction?

Tags: bezier-curves, geometry-nodes

Lets say i have a graph and i want to distribute points on that graph. But i want them to have a equal distance to each other based on the X vector. Does anyone know how to achieve this? [image]

My Node tree:
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some variation on this.

In the case of an XY graph:

1. Capture the positions of the input graph (You could resample it to greater density, if you needed to, for a closer linear interpolation, later)
2. Scale the graph to 0 in Y
3. Evenly resample the curve, while a straight line, to your desired resolution.
4. Offset, (project,) the newly sampled points to an interpolation of the original curve, in Y only.

[image]

Which takes you from here, evenly distributed along the curve's length:

[image]

to here, evenly distributed in X:

[image]

Comment: That would be the better solution, because no duplicate points are being created. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

[image: Blocks evenly distributed]
[image: Geometry Node graph]

You can resample *a lot* and only use some of the new points by limiting the selection using a modulo on the relevant axis.

Comment: That did it! Thank you!

Comment: Ah, i found an issue with this. Because of the resample by a lot, there are duplicate points that are being created and multiple instancens on one location.